# How can I handle an ISP's request for information that our CDN doesn't capture?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, internet-abuse

A hosting provider has responded to my detailed abuse complaint with a request for additional information that [our CDN doesn't capture](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=280901):

> Can you please provide us with exact **source port** number for all the addresses
>   you have sent us. This is crucial, because this is the only way to find users
>   in our system.

I suspect that they're deliberately trying to evade responsibility by making unrealistic demands.

Is their request reasonable? How can I handle this in a way that still holds them accountable?

Comment: It may help us to understand the nature of the abuse. Without it, I suspect all we could do is guess which is something we do not like to do here. Cheers!!

Comment: In this incident spam was submitted to a web form, but my question is about abuse reporting in general.